# The problem of incomplete installation of phpunit files ( The problem has been resolved )

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to install **phpunit** after I put the following command:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^10.2
```

Several sentences appear to me:

```
The "10.2" constraint for "phpunit/phpunit" appears too strict and will likely not match what you want. See https://getcomposer.org/constraints
./composer.json has been created
Running composer update phpunit/phpunit
Loading composer repositories with package information
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL connection timeout), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 26 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.1)        
  - Locking nikic/php-parser (v4.16.0)        
  - Locking phar-io/manifest (2.0.3)
  - Locking phar-io/version (3.2.1)
  - Locking phpunit/php-code-coverage (10.1.2)
  - Locking phpunit/php-file-iterator (4.0.2) 
  - Locking phpunit/php-invoker (4.0.0)
  - Locking phpunit/php-text-template (3.0.0)
  - Locking phpunit/php-timer (6.0.0)
  - Locking phpunit/phpunit (10.2.0)
  - Locking sebastian/cli-parser (2.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit (2.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (3.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/comparator (5.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/complexity (3.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/diff (5.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/environment (6.0.1)
  - Locking sebastian/exporter (5.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/global-state (6.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/lines-of-code (2.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/object-enumerator (5.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/object-reflector (3.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/recursion-context (5.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/type (4.0.0)
  - Locking sebastian/version (4.0.1)
  - Locking theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 26 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    Failed to download sebastian/version from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
    Now trying to download from source

In GitDownloader.php line 82:

  git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download  


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
```

And only 3 files are added: *composer.json*, *compsor.lock* and *vendor* folder which contains an empty folder named *sebastian*

So the setup is incomplete and there are missing files, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: `"The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing"` Your PHP installation still needs the ZIP extension.  https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=82728&p=278561#p278521 or https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+xampp+enable+zip+extension